# как отследить из какого элемента вызвано событие

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, события

Реакт-приложение, есть 3 карты с одной и той же функцией в событии `onClick`. Функция - `classList.toggle`.

Как дать функции понять, из какого элемента вызвано событие, и какой карте нужно изменить стиль? Подозреваю `this`, но где его применить - не понимаю.

```
const PriceCard = () => {

const classArray = [document.querySelector('.first'),
   document.querySelector('.second'),
   document.querySelector('.third'),]

 const changeClass = function(el){
   
   
    classArray.forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.toggle('price-card__active')
    })
 }
 
return(
<div className='general-div'>
 <div className='price-card first' id='1' onClick={changeClass}> </div>
 <div className='price-card second' id='2' onClick={changeClass}></div>
 <div className='price-card third' id='3' onClick={changeClass}></div>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: `el.target.id` чем вас не устраивает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не должны использовать стандартные селекторы javaScript для обращения к DOM элементам, управляемым Реакт, т.к. это может привести к непредсказуемым результатам.

В вашем случае, достаточно получать id элемента, по которому кликнули и его сохранять в стейт.

При рендере проверять значение, сохраненное в стейте и если совпадает, то устанавливать нужный класс

```
const PriceCard = () => {
  const [divActive, setDivActive] = useState("");

  const changeClass = (el) => {
    setDivActive(el.target.id);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="general-div">
      <div
        className={`price-card second ${divActive === "1" ? "price-card__active" : ""}` }
        id="1"
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        ДИВ 1
      </div>
      <div
        className={`price-card second ${divActive === "2" ? "price-card__active" : ""}` }
        id="2"
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        ДИВ 2
      </div>
      <div
        className={`price-card second ${divActive === "3" ? "price-card__active" : ""}` }
        id="3"
        onClick={changeClass}
      >
        ДИВ 3
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Т.к. в вашем примере кода наблюдается дублирование, то рекомендую, одинаковые элементы размещать в массив и рендерить массив, тогда все элементы будут вести себя одинаково и править поведение надо будет в одном месте, а не для каждого элемента.

Comment: [Песочница с данным примером](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-roentgen-vddp4f?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: благодарю за пример, но не могли бы вы подсказать еще кое что. Внутри дива кастомный компонент, который занимает какое-то пространство в диве, как сделать его грубо говоря одним целым с дивом, чтобы на обоих работал онклик и менялись стили для обоих??  если вопрос не понятен отпишите пожалуйста, создам вопрос с примером кода

Comment: @qwothex можно задать клик `={(е) => changeClass(id, e)}` где id это номер див, а e это само событие клика(если нужно). Надо только функцию поменять

Comment: как же функцию поменять?